# On page load jQuery not getting detect the select dropdown value?

Tags: jquery

I can get the value of the option is getting changed, but if I am trying to get the option value when the page loads, getting an error "undefined."

My Code here:

```
<select name="category_01" id="category_01">
<option value="0">--Select Category--</option>
<option value="7">Analysis technique</option>
<option value="6">Analyzed with</option>
<option value="1">CHEMICAL GROUP</option>
<option value="2">Compounds</option>
<option value="3">Detection Tech</option>
<option value="4">Injection Tech</option>
<option value="5">INSTUMENT</option>
<option value="8">Method</option>
</select>
```

Getting a value on page load:

```
$('#category_01').find(':selected').val();
```

above code returns "undefined".
Any help on this...?

Comment: Are you using DOM-Ready-Handler? `$(function(){/*Your code*/});`

Comment: yes I am using the same stuff here....

Comment: Works fine here anyway http://jsfiddle.net/KVLnM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get val() on page load if you put your code in `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($('#category_01').val());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nazmoonnoor/8K4Wt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#category_01').change(function () {
        var cat_value = $('#category_01').val();
    });
});
```

try this

Comment: I am able to get the option value in onchange method...but I want to get the value on page load.

Comment: then do this

$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code here
});

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure jQuery has been loaded or your dom has loaded. 
Check with this : `$('#category_01').val();`

try :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#category_01').val(); // or your own function
    });
```

Comment: I am using like $(function(){ var selectedValue = $('#category_01').val();});